# Regular Expression in a Windows Batch File

Tags: regex, windows, batch-file, rename

I'm looking for way to rename multiple files with a batch job.
Yes, I know there are many Applications around which can achieve this.
But I need an automated way, something like a Batch File which I can call from a Scheduler (SOS Job Scheduler). We need to rename hundreds of files daily!

The Goal is to set the 17-25 charcaters at the beginning of the file.

- 00010028229720270014468393_TB-E.pdf ->  00144683930001002822972027_TB-E.pdf
- 000100282297202700144683931ESR-AF.pdf -> 001446839300010028229720271ESR-AF.pdf
- 00010031141040250016353371ESR-AF.pdf -> 00163533700010031141040251ESR-AF.pdf
- 0001003167580004001667217KTO.pdf -> 0016672170001003167580004KTO.pdf

Here an example which is more clearer:

0001 002822972 027 **001446839** _TB-E .pdf -> **001446839** 0001 002822972 027 _TB-E .pdf

Comment: Wel, sorry - it isn't more clearer. What is the formula for renaming? In each case, the first 16 characters are removed and then replaced - where? In the first and fourth instance, it's between (the next string of numerics) and (the remainder from the first non-numeric). In the second and third, the numeric before the first non-numeric is included in the "tail" - but this isn't the case for the fourth.

Comment: In the lower example I broke the filename in spaces, just to show you which part (Bold) to put in the beginning of the file. In Each File the part from 17 to 25 Character should be moved at the beginning of the file! It's always the part from 17 to 25 Character, which should be moved! Just the Position is important!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=c:\sourcedir"
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (
 'dir /b /a-d "%sourcedir%\*" '
 ) DO (
 SET "name=%%a"
 CALL :transform
)

GOTO :EOF

:transform
ECHO REN "%sourcedir%\%name%" "%name:~16,9%%name:~0,16%%name:~25%"
GOTO :eof
```

The required REN commands are merely `ECHO`ed for testing purposes. After you've verified that the commands are correct, change `ECHO REN` to `REN` to actually rename the files.

Note that the very first example you've presented has ...39**3**_TB-E... in the transformed version, that `3` is missing.

Answer (score 1):

This can be accomplished very simply with the help of [REPL.BAT - a hybrid JScript/batch utility that performs a regex search and replace on each line from stdin and writes the result to stdout](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16735079/1012053). The utility uses only native scripting capabilities that are available to any modern Windows machine from XP onward; no 3rd party executable required. Complete documentation is embedded within the script.

Assuming REPL.BAT is somewhere within your PATH:

```
@echo off
pushd "c:\sourcePath"
for /f "delims=" %%A in (
  'dir /b /a-d *.pdf ^| repl "(.{16})(.{9}).*" "ren \q$&\q \q$2$1*\q" x'
) do %%A
popd
```

Using only native batch commands, without any CALL:

```
@echo off
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
pushd "c:\sourcePath"
for /f "delims=" %%F in ('dir /b /a-d *.pdf') do (
  set "file=%%F"
  setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
  ren "!file!" "!file:~16,9!!file:~0,17!*"
  endlocal
)
popd
```

If you know that none of your file names contain the `!` character, then you can simply enable delayed expansion at the top, and remove both SETLOCAL and ENDLOCAL from within the loop.

Both solutions above rely on the fact that `*` at the end of the target name will preserve the remainder of the original file name. See [How does the Windows RENAME command interpret wildcards?](https://superuser.com/questions/475874/how-does-the-windows-rename-command-interpret-wildcards) for more info.

Answer (score -2):

```
(\d{16})(\d+)(.*?\.pdf)  ->  \2\1\3
```

{16} means you take 16 repetitions (of a digit)