# BATCH file: Scan an imput result for numbers

Tags: batch-file

I'm handling a bat file basically to redirect a streaming media content to VLC, my goal is to pratically automate the whole following steps:

- Open the program that bridges the video stream to VLC (DONE)
- the program gives a list of available resolutions to use as below:

> [cli][info] Found matching plugin ustreamtv for URL
>   blablabla.com/channel/test
>
> Available streams: 480p+ (best), 480p+_alt_akamai,
>   480p+_alt_highwinds, mobile_240p (worst)

Now what i need to do is basically find a way to "scan" this information for numbers in order to automate the following string

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Livestreamer\livestreamer.exe"
ublablabla.com/channel/test %quality%"p+_alt_highwinds" > nul
```

%quality% is there only because I'm currently typing manually whatever resoloution comes out in "Available streams:" to complete the string.

Ther's any way i can filter this result like if there is a 3 digits number before p+_alt_highwinds and automatically complete the string?

I'm sorry if this question looks like a complete mess.

Comment: Have you searched for [regex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21162119/regular-expression-in-a-windows-batch-file)?

Comment: Do you need to extract all the options, or would you be OK with the first one listed, for example?